# Sharepoint 2013: Display Secondary navigation menu URL Links based on current user group membership

Tags: security, navigation, managed, trim, target-audience

Hi I'm new to this and have searched but couldnt quite find the solution. I believe SP Sercices will be the tool, but no examples satisfied my requirement,  hope you can help.

What I have

-Custom Publishing site with main nav and sub nav (store related)

-Main nav is global and all users across sites can access

-Sub navs are store related meaning each of our stores sub nav is proprietary to each stores content.

-Sub nav links are the same for all store sub navs

-example sub nav links: our staff, store news, store calendar.

-Sub nav is using managed terms. *Please inform if using simple links are better approach although id perfer to do this programaticaly rather than manual.

What im trying to do

-Have store sub nav URL links coorelate only to store specific group members. Ex: Florida store users click "our staff" and are taken to Florida store staff page.  When California store users click "our staff" they are taken to California store staff page. This should hold true for all links in sub nav.

Let me know if im lacking information.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know which store the current logged in user belongs to?

Comment: Hi Christophe, thanks for your reply. Site level permissions based on AD groups  determine who can access store sites.   Determining which store the current user belongs to is exactly what I'd like to achieve. My guess is once we know this it can be passed to other controls.  If my jargon is totally off, please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid SharePoint won't be able to tell which AD group the user belongs to.

Here is how I worked around this issue in the past:
- create a list with one item per store (store name or link to the store Web site).
- apply item level permissions, each item (store) being only accessed by its AD group.

Now, when you retrieve this list under the user's credentials (you can use SPServices, but there are other ways), you'll only get the user's store.

Comment: My explanatioion lacked info. SP groups control site permissions by having "AD groups" as group members. Ex: Florida Store Members > Florida Store (AD Group). The secondary nav links are part of a store masterpage all stores use. I want the backend URLs to change based on the user store group membership so when clicked it will direct them to store specific content. Hope I was a biy clearer there.

Comment: @Andre ok, the story is the same if a SharePoint group is wrapped around each AD group. I just outlined the main steps, your question goes byond programming.

Comment: thanks for the follow up. I will go with your recommended approach.  My other thought was to create individual masterpages but based on your input, sounds like I will still be limited due to AD groups.